# Lyx suddenly stopped working, completely lost

Tags: lyx

I've been using Lyx (on windows) to write my thesis and for some reason tonight it just stopped working. If i try opening a new file, no layouts are available. I am able to open my thesis file, but I can not compile it (PdfLatex...). Any tips on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Update (this was the code that had to be changed as per the link in my comment - the 100 was previously a 65):

```
\edef\fmtversion{2005/12/01}  
\iftrue  
\def\reserved@a#1/#2/#3\@nil{%  
\count@\year  
\advance\count@-#1\relax  
\multiply\count@ by 12\relax  
\advance\count@\month  
\advance\count@-#2\relax}  
\expandafter\reserved@a\fmtversion\@nil  
\ifnum\count@>100
```

Comment: I won't be able to help you, but I'm sure that those who could will need further details. For example: the version of Win, Lyx and pdflatex that you use; Any sort of error messages which are generated. Finally, did you try simple kill all Lyx related process and restart?

Comment: its windows 7 and lyx1.6.7. I was trying to use the tikz package and when I tried to run pdflatex the lyx program 'froze'. I was forced to shut it down (task manager). I then used miktex to install pgfplots. It was after this that I tried opening Lyx and found all my layouts unavailable and that I could not compile my thesis document. I tried restarting my computer several times, as well as Lyx reconfigure.

Comment: update: i tried using texworks to compile a latex file that had worked previously and getting errors with that as well. So the issue must be with my Miktex 2.8. Still at a complete loss on how to resolve it.

Comment: Resolved! Followed the small trick from http://blog.eddsn.com/2011/06/latex-source-files-more-than-5-years-old/ and it temporarily fixed the problem.

Comment: @Mendy: Miktex 2.8 has been released 2009. It is quite improbable that its latex has already reached the five-year-limit. Could you please copy all the 10 lines before the `\ifnum` (starting with `\edef\fmtversion`)?

Comment: @Ulrike I updated the questions with the 10 lines.

Comment: @Mendy Your latex.ltx is too old. Did you check for updates with the update manager of miktex? If you have a multiuser installation: check in user mode and in admin mode. (The LaTeX-kernel is in the miktex package ltxbase).